# Intercept Route Request with Angular 2 Router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

With the Angular 2 Router I'd like to capture an event when a route is requested to be activated.  In Angular 1.x I used $locationChangeSuccess, and then checked to see if the user was logged in or not.

I need to do something similar with Angular 2, so I can redirect a user to a login screen if they aren't yet authenticated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at CanActivate and CanDeactivate. The [official angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) give an example of creating an admin guard which I found quite useful when creating a general login guard.

CanActivate is used to check if the router can navigate to the new route, whereas CanDeactivate is used to check if the router can navigate away from the current route. If the guard is present on a route it will check with the guard each time a navigation occurs.

[Here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#can-activate-guard) is a link directly to the example.

Comment: It looks like CanActivate is deprecated.  The docs don't do a good job of keeping up with the releases, from my experience the last few months.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4ipumf/canactivate_not_in_router_as_of_rc1/

Comment: It's back in the new router. It used to be a decorator and now it is an [interface](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html).